# CSS DropDown Menu Bug Fix

Tags: html, css

I have created a DropDown Menu with CSS, but i can't solve one problem: The last Menu element's width is smaller than the DropDown's width.
Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/eeFdP/

I could maybe use width to solve the problem temporarily, but it is not a logical and permanent solution, considering that the menu could extend with new elements.
Please help?

HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">By contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">By email</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
```

CSS code:

```
.clear {
        clear:both;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    ul>li {
        float:left;
    }

    ul>li>a {
        display:block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        color:#000;
        text-decoration:none;
        background:#fff;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    ul>li>a:hover {
        background-color:#bbb;
        color:white;
    }

    ul>li>ul {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
    }
    ul>li>ul>li {
        float:none;
    }
    ul>li:hover>ul {
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Not understanding the problem all menu items appear to have the same width to me. Please indicate which item you're having issues with ('Contact' or 'Javascript and 'By email') and let us know what browsers you've tested this on.

Comment: I believe the OP means that the top level menu is narrower than the contents of the drop down.  @user2653125 - It's actually the same for the center menu as well, but the difference is smaller, so it is harder to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `absolute` positioning on your dropdowns, you can use a `relative` position with `0` height and `overflow: visible`. Also, instead of `display: none/block` you can use `visibility: hidden/visible`. This will make the parent elements know the with of its children.

http://jsfiddle.net/eeFdP/4/

```
ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

ul > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a width to your parent element.  Like so:

CSS:

```
.clear {
            clear:both;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        ul>li {
            float:left;
        }

        ul>li>a {
            width: 100px; /*-- Added width, specify to your liking --*/
            display:block;
            padding:5px 10px;
            color:#000;
            text-decoration:none;
            background:#fff;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        }
        ul>li>a:hover {
            background-color:#bbb;
            color:white;
        }

        ul>li>ul {
            position:absolute;
            display:none;
        }
        ul>li>ul>li {
            float:none;
        }
        ul>li:hover>ul {
            display:block;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">By contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">By email</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>I am a paragraph.</p>
```

Here is a working jsfiddle as well to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/eeFdP/1/

That should do the trick mate, hope that helps ;)

Comment: The OP mentioned not wanting to use width explicitly… though I'm not sure there is a solution in that case :)

Comment: agreed, I think his/her best bet would be to apply width in this case

Comment: if the menu container width is known, you can use the calc() value to easily distribute the widths appropriately without needing to set a specific width other than the container. For example: ul>li>a {width: calc(600px / 4);} This would make each nav item 150px wide based on a 600px wide container. Careful with browser support: http://caniuse.com/calc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding relative positioning to your list items forces the last drop-menu to be flush with the menu on the right side.

http://jsfiddle.net/eeFdP/3/

```
ul>li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```